# This if is not working on Octave/Matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement, octave

I have the code divided on three functions:

`f.m` (This function **works**)

```
function y=f(x)
y = x^2;
endfunction
```

`df.m` (The function that return the derivate of `y=x^2`. This function **works**)

```
function y=df(i)
  syms x,diff(f(x),x);
  subs(ans,x,i);
  y = ans;
endfunction
```

`newton.m` (`maxIt` = max of tries)

```
function [x1,nIt] = newton (f,df,x0,tol,maxIt)
   k=0;
   x=x0;
   nIt = 0;
   while (k<maxIt)
     if(df(x)== 0)
       fprintf("La derivada, da resultado 0");
       k=maxIt;
     else
       i = x - (f(x)/df(x))
       x = i;
       nIt = nIt + 1
       k=k+1;
     endif
  end
endfunction
```

Ok, I executed the command `newton(@f,@df,0,10,2)`. Two-thirds of the program works OK, but if I do `df(0)`, the result is `0` but the `if` doesn't work. I verified that `df(0)` returns 0, and it's OK.

I´m new in MATLAB/Octave.

Comment: what is your problem? What doe "the if dont workd" mean? If I use your code I see the message as expected since df(0)==0. This means you've found your extrema. And btw: don't use "ans" in your scripts....

Answer (score 1):

You have several mistakes in your code. Not all of them are directly relevant, but fixing all of them will make your code more readable and robust.

The function `f` if fine.

The function `df` assumes that `f` is known somehow, but it's not a good practice. you better pass `f` too to this function. Also, don't use `ans` as a variable, store your intermediate result in different variables. This is how df should look:

```
function y = df(f,a)
syms x
d = diff(f(x),x);
y = subs(d,x,a);
end
```

Now you have to change all the calls to `df` in your `newton` function to `df(f,x)`. I'm not sure what is your final goal, but right now, the variables `x1` and `tol` are not in use in any way.

Hope it solves the problem ;)